# PapaParse CSV to JSON - transformHeader callback not called

Tags: javascript, json, csv, plugins, papaparse

As per the documentation, I see a "transformHeader" call back function in config.

https://www.papaparse.com/docs#config

I have tried using this, but no luck. transformHeader callback is not being called.

Has anyone tried this?

Regards,
Puli

Comment: Maybe shear the code that does not work and/or the errors...

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post on github:](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/issues/597)

> The transformHedaer [sic] function is only available on 5.0.0 version which is currently unreleased and only available on master branch using non minified file.